# Retrieving Permission of ListItem

Tags: 2013, permissions, groups, list-item

For sites, we always use the web context to retrieve all the groups for the site. However, I have requirement to retrieve all the users and groups for a list item. The list item has its own permission setting. How can I programmatically retrieve the users and groups (that is tied to the item) and the SPRoleType using Server Side Object Model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply loop through all `SPRoleAssignment` in `item.RoleAssignments`. The `Member` property gives you the user (actual user or AD group) or the SP group, and the `RoleDefinitionBindings` gives you the associated role(s) for that member.